# Update Scripts PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html

I have a very simple website that has a button to allow people to post a photo.
I wrote a PHP script that uploads the photo to me web server.

My question now is how would I go about having the website update its homepage to include the new photo? Would I need some kind of script for generating HTML and saving it file? I know Wordpress and some other companies provide the functionality but I am just doing a very simple setup and don't feel like signing up or paying for an account.

Any leads would help.
Thanks!

Comment: Is this a site where the homepage is dynamically generated to the specific use? Or is it a site that only has one main user, such as for a small company?

Comment: One main user. I mean that could change but for now I just want to not have to monitor it and have it update itself to host content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PHP file that serves your home page you will need to read the uploaded files and create image tags for them. If you moved the files to a directory under the web server root, you can use the following.

**homepage.php**

```
<?php
$path = 'where/your/images/are/';
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry !== '.' && $entry !== '..') {
            echo "<img src='{$path}{$entry}' /><br />";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But you should not be storing user uploaded content under your web server's root directory. Here is an alternative scheme to get you heading in the right direction.

**upload.php**

```
$uploadsDir = '/not/under/web/root';

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] !== 0) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 internal server error");
    die();
}

$tmpName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

$info = getimagesize($tmpName); 

if (is_array($info) && array_key_exists('mime', $info) && $info['mime'] === 'image/jpeg') {
    $name = sha1($tmpName) . '.jpg';
    move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $uploadsDir . $name);
    echo "Image uploaded<br />";
}
else {
    echo "Sorry we only take jpegs<br />";
}
```

**homepage.php**

```
<?php
$path = '/not/under/web/root/';
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry !== '.' && $entry !== '..') {
            echo "<img src='imagefetcher.php?id={$entry}' /><br />";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**imagefetcher.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['img']) && !empty($_GET['img'])) {
    $img = $_GET['img'];
    // since we know that all files in this directory are sha1 digests followed by .jpg
    //  make sure that $img matches $pattern
    $pattern = "/^[0-9a-f]{40}\\.jpg$/";
    $success = preg_match($pattern, $img);

    if ($success === 1) {
        $fp = fopen('/not/under/web/root/' . $img, 'rb');
        if ($fp) {
            header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize('not/under/web/root/' . $img));
            fpassthru($fp);
            die();
        }
        fail();
    }
    fail();
}
fail();

function fail() {
    header("HTTP/1.1 400 malformed request");
    die();
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot@ This is what I was looking for-something to get me started. I will delve into this a bit more and see what I can muster up. Thanks again! I will let you know how it all comes together.